# A fatal error has been detected by the JRE

Tags: java

I generated JAR in win7-32bit,but I run the JAR in win7-64bit.

```
> #
> # A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
> #
> #  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x0000000002e74c5d, pid=7852, tid=4024
> #
> # JRE version: 7.0_25-b17
> # Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (23.25-b01 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
> # Problematic frame:
> # J  org.apache.http.impl.cookie.BestMatchSpec.formatCookies(Ljava/util/List;)Ljava/util/List;
> #
> # Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
> #
> # If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
> #   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
> #
```

I don't know why throw this error.Can anyone have solution for this?

Comment: And do you have a minimal working example of this .jar crashing your application? Like `import thatthing; public class Test { public static void main(String[] args) { /* try to use thatthing */ } }`?

Answer (score 2):

There is a bug in java JIT compiler. https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8021898

Fixed in 1.7u60 and 1.8. Otherwise if you can't update you can temporarily add -XX:-LoopUnswitching to your server startup to disable loop unswitching.

Comment: -XX:-LoopUnswitchin is a typo, it should be -XX:-LoopUnswitching